# How to validate google ReCaptcha Enterprise at server? It does't have a 'secret' associated with 'site key ID'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, recaptcha

The enterprise version doesn't have the "Site Key Secret". I can see only the "Site Key ID"

https://console.cloud.google.com/security/recaptcha

Comment: If you go to https://google.com/recaptcha/admin , choose the website you created your API keys for, and click on cog wheel on the right upper corner, You will see recaptcha type and reCaptcha keys, click on that to view keys you have created. It shows you Site key AND secret key.
https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/create-key
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq